# Low memory usage queries

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm working on a dashboard app on vb.net and it has gotten to a point where the number of queries are overwhelming and use too much memory as time goes on and since this is gonna be meant to run for months non stop, I'd like to know if there are ways to display the number of database entries on a label with low memory usage in the long run.
My code for this is as follows and uses alot of memory (the ammount of queries i'm gonna need is between 14-25, so that's a problem.

```
    GeneralCommand = String.Format("SELECT * FROM fpscdb001_ws_017.ticket WHERE created_on > cast(dateadd(day, -120, getdate()) as date)  AND status_1 = 'In Progress'")
    sdaAllPending = New SqlDataAdapter(GeneralCommand, conn)
    Dim num_pending = sdaAllPending.Fill(data_set, "fpscdb001_ws_017.ticket")
    t_pending.Text = num_pending
```

Comment: Consider making one query that returns all the data unfiltered (if that's possible in your case) and then do the filtering later like this:

`Dim dr as DataRow = MyDataSet.Tables("TableName").Select("Filter=True", "SortOrder")`

That way you hit the actual database only once.

Comment: Yes if you build one generic datatable (`SELECT * FROM foo`),  You could then filter that or run queries against it to get subsets.  Make sure you disposing of things that ought to be disposed

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this to my code? i feel it my code for a large number of queries is not that great and i'm inclining over to making a new bit of code for my queries

Comment: Bringing great gobs of data into an application and filtering it there has the potential to overwhelm that application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want a count of how many records you are retrieving there is no need to bring back all of those records into a dataset unless you need to use the dataset.

Change the query to return a count of records instead and then display that value.

```
GeneralCommand = String.Format("SELECT Count(*) FROM fpscdb001_ws_017.ticket WHERE created_on > cast(dateadd(day, -120, getdate()) as date)  AND status_1 = 'In Progress'")
sdaAllPending = New SqlDataAdapter(GeneralCommand, conn)
Dim num_pending = sdaAllPending.Fill(data_set, "fpscdb001_ws_017.ticket")
t_pending.Text = data_set.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
```

Comment: Your code is exactly the new code i was trying to come up, thanks a bunch, I will try this and see if the performance is better

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! Memory use dropped from multiple gigs over just a few mins to just 60 mb, you saved my butt